# tikzcd - Spacing issues

Tags: tikz-cd

I have created the following diagram (I just added a box around it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
   \begin{tikzcd} 
       \ar[loop left, in=150, out=-150, distance=2cm,"-1"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=148, out=-148, distance=3cm, "-2"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=5cm, "-k"']  
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=6cm, phantom, "\dots"'] m 
       \ar[loop above, in=60, out=120, distance=1cm,"\id_m"] 
       \ar[loop right, in=30, out=-30,distance=2cm,"+1"] 
       \ar[loop right, in=32, out=-32, distance=3cm, "+2"] 
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"]  
       \ar[loop right, in=34, out=-34, distance=5cm, "+k"] 
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=6cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"] 
   \end{tikzcd}}
\end{document}
```

The diagram is exactly as I wanted, but there is way too much space before and after. How to correct for that? Adding

```
 \vspace*{xxx}
```

is clearly a possibility, but I found it to be too much of a hack. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code. - Do you mean (whitespace) above and below?

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
\begin{tikzcd}[
     execute at begin picture={
       \useasboundingbox (-4.5,-1.5) rectangle (4.5,1.5);
     }
]
```

It does require a bit of trial and error to find appropriate coordinates though.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
   \begin{tikzcd}[
        execute at begin picture={
          \useasboundingbox (-4.5,-1.5) rectangle (4.5,1.5);
         }
       ]
       \ar[loop left, in=150, out=-150, distance=2cm,"-1"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=148, out=-148, distance=3cm, "-2"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"'] 
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=5cm, "-k"']  
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=6cm, phantom, "\dots"'name=dot1] m 
       \ar[loop above, in=60, out=120, distance=1cm,"id_m"] 
       \ar[loop right, in=30, out=-30,distance=2cm,"+1"] 
       \ar[loop right, in=32, out=-32, distance=3cm, "+2"] 
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"]  
       \ar[loop right, in=34, out=-34, distance=5cm, "+k"] 
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=6cm, font=\tiny, phantom, 
          "\dots"name=dot2] 
\end{tikzcd}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with your diagram I achieved this:

[image]

(blind text just to give a context).

<s>The problem seems to be that the diagram has both height and depth too big, for some reason I don't understand.</s>

## Edit:

The problem is, as @TorbjørnT. said, because `\fbox` includes the control points of the curve in the frame. So **the solution below works only in case the diagram is symmetric!** If the diagram is not symmetric, this solution will not work, unfortunately...

To work around the issue I used a modified version of a `\putbox` macro I had done a few weeks ago. The macro will draw a box around the diagram considering only its height, but not its depth.

Its not pretty, but I think it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\newcommand{\putbox}[2][]{%
\ifdefined\xboxh%
  \relax%
\else%
  \newlength{\xboxh}%
  \newlength{\xboxw}%
  \newlength{\xboxd}%
\fi%
\settoheight{\xboxh}{#2}%
\settowidth{\xboxw}{#2}%%
\settodepth{\xboxd}{#2}%
\frame{\phantom{\rule{\xboxw}{\dimexpr\xboxh}}}%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \relax%
\else%
  \setlength{\xboxh}{0.5\xboxw}%
  \settowidth{\xboxw}{#1}%
  \setlength{\xboxw}{0.5\xboxw}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr-\xboxw-\xboxh}%
  \vskip-\xboxh%
  #1%
  \hspace{\dimexpr \xboxh-\xboxw}%
  \vskip\xboxd%
  \vskip-\xboxh%
\fi\relax%
}

\newcommand{\mycd}{%
   \begin{tikzcd}%
       \ar[loop left, in=150, out=-150, distance=2cm,"-1"']%
       \ar[loop left, in=148, out=-148, distance=3cm, "-2"']%
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom,%
          "\dots"']%
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=5cm, "-k"']%
       \ar[loop left, in=146, out=-146, distance=6cm, phantom, "\dots"'] m %
       \ar[loop above, in=60, out=120, distance=1cm,"Id_m"]%
       \ar[loop right, in=30, out=-30,distance=2cm,"+1"]%
       \ar[loop right, in=32, out=-32, distance=3cm, "+2"]%
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=3.7cm, font=\tiny, phantom,%
          "\dots"]%
       \ar[loop right, in=34, out=-34, distance=5cm, "+k"]%
       \ar[loop left, in=34, out=-34, distance=6cm, font=\tiny, phantom,%
          "\dots"]%
\end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\putbox[\mycd]{\mycd}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is that control points created by TikZ during the creation of the loops influence the bounding box.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So the `\fbox` also captures the control points of the bezier curves? In this case my solution works by mere coincidence?

Comment: The `\fbox` captures the area of the `tikzpicture`, and that area includes those control points. I don't know what your solution does exactly, so can't comment on coincidence.

Comment: Hahaha. Yes, one implies the other :P. And I thought I made something great...