# How to repair Dimension too large when I draw this triangle?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I use this code to draw triangle. When I choose `a = b = c = 5`, I got the result.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, border = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\myr{{sqrt(- pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)* pow(\c,2)/(pow(\a,4)  + pow(\b,4)  + pow(\c,4)- 2 *pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)  - 2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\b,2)-2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\a,2) ))}}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\c,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at  ({(pow(\b,2) + pow(\c,2) - pow(\a,2))/(2*\c)},{sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c) *(-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))/(2*\c)},0);
    \coordinate (T) at  (\c/2, {\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c)))},0);

    \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/above,T/below}
    {
        \fill (\point) circle (1.8pt);
        \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (\myr); 
    \end{scope} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

If I use `a = b = c = 6` or larger, I cannot obtain the result. How can I get the result?

Comment: Your code draws a circle seen in perspective, why would you want it to draw a triangle?

Comment: @AndréC This is only one part of a completed code.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. In addition, you do not use in this code `pgfplots`. Please make a minimum example that contains only the necessary packages.

Comment: Do not use `pow(\a,2)` etc instead of `\a*\a`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo And how about `a^4`?

Comment: `\a*\a*\a*\a`  BTW, one should expand the polynomial `$ax^2+bx+c$` as `(a*x+b)*x+c`.  It is both faster and more accurate (roundoff).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I replaced, I cannot obtain the result.

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to solve your dynamic range problem.  pgfmath is constantly switching from text to lengths (10,000 max) to FPU registers and back.  You might try normalizing \a, \b and \c then applying the scale factor to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some standard ways to deal with this. One of them is to use the `fpu` library. (`fpu` is mentioned in the [comment by John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503791/how-to-repair-dimension-too-large-when-i-draw-this-triangle#comment1272591_503791), but I do not have the problems mentioned there.) However, as you noted yourself in some constructions like `arc` just switching on `fpu` can lead to problems. In order to make things more convenient for you, I added a macro `\PgfmathsetmacroFPU`, which switches the library on locally, parses the expression, and "smuggles" the result out of the group. Therefore, the definition of the macro will be local, just like in the case of the ordinary `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Note that `\pgfmathsmuggle` has been added to the more recent versions of `pgf`, so if you have an outdated TeX installation it may not work. Sorry overleaf users! Further information on smuggling as well as alternative commands can be found in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470961/121799).

```
\documentclass[12pt, border = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,backgrounds,fpu} 
\newcommand{\PgfmathsetmacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{6} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{6} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{6} 
    \PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myr}{{sqrt(-
     pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)* pow(\c,2)/ (pow(\a,4)  + pow(\b,4)  + pow(\c,4)- 2
     *pow(\a,2) *pow(\b,2)  - 2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\b,2)-2*pow(\c,2) *pow(\a,2) ))}}
    \PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\Angleone}{-90} 
    \PgfmathsetmacroFPU{\Angletwo}{60}
    \coordinate (E) at ({\c/2 + \myr*cos(\Angleone)},{\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b -
     \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))) +
     \myr*sin(\Angleone)},0 );  \coordinate (F) at ({\c/2 +
    \myr*cos(\Angletwo)},{\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c)
     *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))) + \myr*sin(\Angletwo)},0 ); 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\c,0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at  ({(pow(\b,2) + pow(\c,2) - pow(\a,2))/(2*\c)},{sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c) *(-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))/(2*\c)},0);
    \coordinate (T) at  (\c/2, {\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c)))},0);
    \foreach \point/\position in {A/left,B/below,C/above,T/below}
    {
        \fill (\point) circle (1.8pt);
        \node[\position=3pt] at (\point) {$\point$};
    }
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (\myr); 
    \end{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angleone}{-90} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angletwo}{60}  
    \draw[thick] (E) arc[start angle=\Angleone,end angle=\Angletwo,radius=\myr]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I add `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Angleone}{-90}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angletwo}{60}` and 
`\coordinate (E) at ({\c/2 + \myr*cos(\Angleone)},{\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))) +  \myr*sin(\Angleone)},0 );
 \coordinate (F) at ({\c/2 + \myr*cos(\Angletwo)},{\c* (\a*\a + \b*\b - \c*\c)/(2*sqrt((\a+\b-\c) *(\a-\b+\c)* (-\a+\b+\c)* (\a+\b+\c))) +  \myr*sin(\Angletwo)},0 );
\draw [thick] (E) arc (\Angleone:\Angletwo:\myr);`
I cannot obtain the result. Please help me.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, good point: some constructions like `arc` have problems with `fpu`. I added general way to fix this: a macro `\PgfmathsetmacroFPU` that switches on the library only locally in the parsing.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: How can I show coordinates of the point `T` and radius `myr` below the figure?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I do not know, which is why I asked this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503603/121799. AFAIK there is no built-in way that allows us to store the 3d coordinates in points.

Comment: I have removed some comments here which seem to constitute a separate question rather than a clarification of this answer. The answer here is appropriate to the question posed, and the generic technical issue raised in comments would be better handled separately.