# Conformal mapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, mapping

I am trying to draw this [image]

So far I have

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,2)node[anchor=south east] {y}; 
    \draw[-stealth] (-2,-1) -- (2,-1) node[anchor=north west] {x}; 
    \fill[step=0.1cm,black,thick] (-2,-1) grid (1,1);
    \path(0.1,1.1) node{$\pi$};
    \path(1,-1.2) node{$1$};
    \path (1.8,1.8) node{$\mathbb{C}$};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=R]
    \draw[-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,2)node[anchor=south east] {v}; 
    \draw[-stealth] (-2,-1) -- (2,-1) node[anchor=north west] {u}; 

    \clip[draw](0,-1) circle (1cm);
    \draw [step=0.1cm,black,thick] (-2,-1) grid (1,1);
    \path (1.8,1.8) node{$\mathbb{C}$};
    \end{scope}
    %
    \draw[-latex] (L.east) -- (L.east-|R.west) node[midway,above]{$f(z)=e^z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the below. Can someone help me? [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tikz - generic conformal map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513088/tikz-generic-conformal-map)

Comment: @ABlueChameleon if i completely understood the code i bet it would, but im very new in this so it is too much for me to handle, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution (i.e. one that'd work for any/most functions f(x)), or just to illustrate this particular example? If the former's the case, the PGF command `\pgftransformcm` (p. 1155 of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) helps for simple (a.k.a. linear) transformations.

Comment: i would like this specific case only, but thanks for the manual!

Answer (score 11):

#### Somewhat General Answer / Basic Idea

A somewhat general way to typeset conformal mappings, with thanks to [@Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat) for their wonderful [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539543/170958) to my question. Also see that answer, or [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513092/170958) of theirs, or the [fpu](/questions/tagged/fpu) tag, for examples of how to use the `fpu` TikZ library ([pp. 691–698](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.691) of the TikZ & PGF manual), which, though I'm not using it below, might often be convenient to avoid some `dimension too large` errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

% http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.123
\usepackage{tikz}
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.1162
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations} 

% Define your R^2 -> R^2 function parametrically, i.e. f(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))
% Set \xnew to u(x,y), accessing the variables x and y through \pgf@x and \pgf@y
% The divisions and multiplication by 1cm are for consistency of units, see
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539543/170958
% To see how you can enter what kind of formulas, see
% http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.1029
\makeatletter
\def\customtransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xnew}{%
        (  (\pgf@x/1cm) - (\pgf@y/1cm)^2 + 1  )*1cm % u(x,y) = x - y^2 + 1
    }%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ynew}{%
        (  (\pgf@x/1cm) + (\pgf@y/1cm)  )*1cm % v(x,y) = x + y
    }%
    \pgf@x=\xnew pt%
    \pgf@y=\ynew pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black!30] (0, 0) grid (2, 2);
    % smoother plot, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539543/170958
    % or http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.1164
    \pgfsettransformnonlinearflatness{1pt}
    \pgftransformnonlinear{\customtransformation}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (2, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Reproducing the actually desired output

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations} 

\makeatletter
\def\customtransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xnew}{%
        (exp(\pgf@x/1cm))*cos(deg(\pgf@y/1cm))*1cm % u(x,y) = e^x * cos(y)
    }%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ynew}{%
        (exp(\pgf@x/1cm))*sin(deg(\pgf@y/1cm))*1cm % v(x,y) = e^x * sin(y)
    }%
    \pgf@x=\xnew pt%
    \pgf@y=\ynew pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\scalebox{.5}{% to make the tikzpicture fit on the page, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\npi{3.1415926536}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-8cm]
        \draw[step=\npi/10, black!25, thin] (-2*\npi,0) grid (0.3*\npi, 1*\npi);
        \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3.75) node[above] {$\Im(z)$}; 
        \draw[->] (-7,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$\Re(z)$}; 
        \draw (0.3*\npi,.1) -- (0.3*\npi,-.1) node[below] {$\frac{3\pi}{10}$};
        \draw (.1,1*\npi) -- (-.1,1*\npi) node[above left] {$\pi$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,3.75) node[above] {$\Im(f(z))$}; 
        \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$\Re(f(z))$}; 
        \draw ({exp(.3*\npi)},.1) -- ({exp(.3*\npi)},-.1) node[below] {$e^{\frac{3\pi}{10}}$};
        \pgfsettransformnonlinearflatness{1pt}
        \pgftransformnonlinear{\customtransformation} % NB: this will cancel the shift from \begin{scope}, so I put the shift in the first scope instead
        \draw[step=\npi/10, black!25, thin] (-2*\npi,0) grid (0.3*\npi, 1*\npi);
    \end{scope} % ending the scope ends the, well, scope, of the transformation
    \draw[-latex] (-5.5,1) -- (-4,1) node[midway,above] {$f(z)=e^z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Previous Approach

Adapted from the [PGF / TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), p. 1162. Check it out for an in-depth explanation. In short, `\def` defines a new transformation, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` change the meaning of `@`, allowing you to access the `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` variables, among others. Of course, you could always plot these things manually with TikZ by calculating what the output should be yourself, but that sounds tedious to me. You should be able to easily add axes or more labels as desired.

**Edit:** Warning - **Mathematical Mistake**: the below actually represents `f(x,y) = (y * cos(x). y * (sin(x))`, not `(e^x * cos(y), e^x * sin(y))`. My bad, sorry. For the latter, see the new approach at the top. To typeset the former with that approach too, you can use `(\pgf@y/1cm)*cos(deg(\pgf@x/1cm))*1cm` and `(\pgf@y/1cm)*sin(deg(\pgf@x/1cm))*1cm` as formulas for `\xnew` and `\ynew`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations} 

\makeatletter
\def\polartransformation{%
% \pgf@x will contain the radius
% \pgf@y will contain the distance
\pgfmathsincos@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}%
% pgfmathresultx is now the cosine of radius and
% pgfmathresulty is the sine of radius
\pgf@x=\pgfmathresultx\pgf@y%
\pgf@y=\pgfmathresulty\pgf@y%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(-8,0)}]
        \draw(-3.15,-2) grid[xstep=0.3,ystep=0.3] (3.15,2);
        \draw[->] (4,0) -- node[above] {$f(z)=e^z$} (5,0);
    \end{scope}

    % Start nonlinear transformation
    \pgftransformnonlinear{\polartransformation}

    % Draw something with this transformation in force
    \draw(-3.15,-2) grid[xstep=0.3,ystep=0.3] (3.15,2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: how could i manipulate the angle of the circle, in order to only draw half a circle?

Comment: @riemannfanboy Quick dirty fix would be to clip it

Comment: well i clipped it and now its perfect

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Wow.